# Deleting a dynamically created button a runtime

Tags: delphi

I need the user to be able to right click the button and it deletes itself but the following code isn't working

```
        procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);         ////////Creates a new object
        var
        ExampleButton : TButton;
        Begin
            ExampleButton := TButton.Create(self);  //Creates an object the same as its self
            ExampleButton.Parent := self;
//Button properties go here

//Procedures called here            
            ExampleButton.OnMouseDown := DragOrDelete;                          

        end;
```

Above creates the button, below I try to delete it

```
procedure TForm1.DragOrDelete(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin

  CursorPosition := Mouse.CursorPos;          ////Location of mouse
  ExampleButtonStartingLocation := TPoint.Create((Sender as Tbutton).Left, (Sender as Tbutton).Top);
  if Button = mbRight then
  FreeAndNil(TButton);
end;
```

The error I get is constant object cannot be passed as a var parameter.
Is it because I create numerous TButtons but the program doesn't know which one to refer one.

Comment: `TButton` is a class **type**, not a class instance, so you cannot free it.  Maybe you mean `Button`?

Comment: You are attempting to destroy a type. `TButton` is a type. In any case, you cannot destroy the button in its own event handler, because when that event handler returns, code of that instance executes. But if you've destroyed the instance, then it's game over. So you need to queue the button deletion until it has finished processing its messages.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan which answer do you recommend using below as a solution to this problem?

Comment: They both say much the same thing, although Arioch's answer is exceptionally long-winded.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've been banned from asking questions. As a mod would you be able to tell me why I can't ask more questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well,

```
FreeAndNil(TButton);
```

should be

```
(Sender as TButton).Free;  // thanks to DH
```

But this is not good. The RTL routines that call the event handler will still have a reference to the button, and need to continue accessing it after the event handler exits, so freeing it may cause further problems (also, `Sender` is not a `var` parameter, so setting it to `nil` will have no effect in the caller).

A better option might be to do something like creating a custom message with `Sender` as the `wParam` and posting it to the main form.

### Edit

To do this you would create a user message, e.g.

```
const
  WM_DELETE_CONTROL = WM_USER +1;
```

and replace the offending line with

```
PostMessage( FormMain.WindowHandle, WM_DELETE_CONTROL, WPARAM( Sender ), 0 );
```

Then create a procedure in your main form to handle the message, e.g.

```
procedure DestroyButton( var Msg : TMessage); message WM_DELETE_CONTROL;
```

with a definition like

```
procedure TForm1.DestroyButton( var Msg : TMessage);
begin
   //      RemoveControl( TButton( Msg.LParam ));
   // correction - thanks to Remy Lebeau
   TButton( Msg.WParam ).Free;
end;
```

Comment: I think that OP's core problem is that they are not storing a reference to each instance in the first place. As I understand, there could be 100 button instances but that one reference will only carry a pointer to the last one created.

Comment: @JerryDodge he is using the button handler event, so sender will be the appropriate button even if there are 100 buttons

Comment: @Dsm but `Sender` is LOCAL variable and there is no point to nil it. Just `Sender.Destroy` is all you need. And voodoo with Process Messages is not required given VCL implementation that carefully avoids the trap, until in XE2

Comment: @Dsm Right, I was referring to "The routines that call this routine will still have a reference to the button..." I'm not sure which references you're speaking of, since every reference is lost as soon as the routine exits actually. The only way to possibly reference it is via an event's `Sender` parameter, as your answer is pointing out.

Comment: @Arioch'The Interesting that VCL carefully avoids the trap of a component being destroying during an event driver. If that is right, then yes, my first correction is OK, and the delay is not required. Yes, I know FreeAndNil is pointless (I actually said that in the original post), but was just correcting the syntax at that point.

Comment: @JerryDodge, yes perhaps I worded it badly. VCL will itself call the event handler. I was merely pointing out that just because the parameter is nilled here, it won't be nilled in the VCL routine that called the event driver.

Comment: VCL is build around short WM_xxx and CM_xxx event handlers. Here, after the button is deleted, it just quickly unrolls the stack. There is just no any other statement - only exiting one function after another.See, any code that does not access `Self` would be safe here, but there not just merely is no any code accessing `Self` hereafter - there is almost no any code at all ! Well, at the very end of stack chain there two GLOBAL no-param procedures called like `FreeDeviceContexts` by `TControl` class. And that is all.

Comment: Any code like "now repaint the button is no more pressed" would be executed as response to WM_PAINT... which never comes because there is no more button. VCL design is strongly decoupled by splitting between two mirroring objects, HWND one and VCL one and leaving most of behavior inside GDI. Sometimes it makes VCL slow or short-featured. But it also solves such traps "for granted". Then again, it is not warranted to work with non-VCL buttons (3rd party, TBitBtn, etc) or non-VCL forms (FMX, Apple). All in all, I personally think PostMessage approach is too old-school to be used today :-D

Comment: @Arioch'The Yes, obviously only applies to VCL. Then again, I am old school ;-) I guess all in all try the simple, and if you have problems try something more complicated, so broadly I agree with what you are saying.

Comment: `RemoveControl()` does not free the button, it will only remove the button from the Form's list of child controls. To actually free the button, the message procedure should use `TButton(Msg.LParam).Free;` instead.

Comment: @Dsm are you old school enough to know what is coup de grace? then i'll follow with two quotes: PostMessage( FormMain.WindowHandle, WM_DELETE_CONTROL, **WPARAM** ( Sender ), 0 ); and TButton( Msg. **LParam** ).  See - old school voodoo magic makes bad things with zombies :-D

Comment: @Arioch'The and if you are really paranoid, posting to `WindowHandle` should be replaced with `Handle` instead, and then thrown away since `(Window)Handle` is not guaranteed  (but likely) to remain alive between the time the message is posted and the time it is dispatched, so you should post to a more persistent window like `Application.Handle` or `AllocateHWnd()` instead.

Comment: `FreeAndNil(Sender as TButton);` is a compiler error

Comment: @Dsm One problem with your solution is that once i delete a button the next button i hover over automatically sticks to the cursor, as if it has been pressed. How can i fix this?

Comment: @Dsm Never mind i fixed it by putting a begin and end around it

Answer (score 0):

You should make two changes there.

1) you should remember which object you created into a variable, living long enough that both procedures can access it.

2) you should destroy that object by the variable, mentioned above

Right now you are trying to destroy just some any random button. But that is hardly what you need! You probably want to destroy exactly the button you was creating, not some another one.

So:

1) `FTableButton` should be moved out of `procedure TForm1.Button1Click` and promoted into a variable of `TForm1` class.

2) `procedure TForm1.Button1Click` should check if the button was already created and not create the second, third, forth... buttons.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);      
var
  TableString : String;
Begin
   if nil <> Self.FTableButton then
      raise Exception.Create('Dynamic button already exists!!!');

    TableString := IntToStr(TableNumber);
    Self.FTableButton := TButton.Create(self);   

....
```

Alternatively, you might choose to delete already existing button (if any) before creating a new one. Usually that is not a good idea, but in some specific scenarios it might make sense (when you need to "reset" the button object, to drop old customized object and create a new one with non-customized default properties).

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);      
var
  TableString : String;
Begin
  Self.FTableButton.Free; // if there already was a dynamic button - destroy it

  TableString := IntToStr(TableNumber);
  Self.FTableButton := TButton.Create(self);   

....
```

3) Now that you have that specific button remembered inside form's `FTableButton` variable you can use it to delete that very specific object.

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
...
  if Button = mbRight then
     FreeAndNil( Self.FTableButton );
end;
```

---

Now there is another potential issue here - the "cleanup after suicide" issue.

David Heffernan in comments states that you can not delete the `TButton` from its own event handler. David states that after you exit the `TForm1.ButtonMouseDown` procedure the just deleted button would (or at least potentially may) do some more after-event actions with itself without recognizing it was already deleted, leading to any potential error, most probably Access Violation of nil dereference kind.

I can agree with half of that claim.

1) using `TForm` and `TButton` from VCL library for Windows is safe, because VCL (at least in Delphi XE2 version) was carefully designed to avoid this trap. The button's internal event calling sequence is designed to never directly address itself after the `TForm1.ButtonMouseDown` exited. So, at least in that narrow case David is not correct and that is safe thing to do.

2) That is called "relying over implementation detail" however. It is bad style because it is fragile. It might work in some specific case but suddenly break from many other reasons.

As soon as you would switch from the standard VCL `TButton` to some other fancy buttons from any other library ( Dev Express, LMD, TMS, anything ) that code my suddenly broke. Or you might switch form VCL to FMX. Or switch from FMX/Win32 to FMX/Android.

Or maybe just upgrading Delphi to some newer version would have VCL broken in that regard (that is highly unlikely but possible nonetheless).

So, to play safe you have to **decouple** those two actions: the button's event handling and the process of its deletion. There are many possible ways to do it, but they all demand more or less extra work and some understanding more issues. Those ways I see split into two avenues.

1) Timing would not change, killing the button would be immediate. But it should not be button deleting itself, it should be some other component.

That is the approach I like the most. I think deleting button on right-click is not the good idea. User might click it randomly, by mistake, by sudden twitch of the hand. Doing something as extreme as suddenly deleting button would be way too harsh change for a random erratic action.

I think you should go traditional way here. Right click should open the context menu, and in the menu there should be the command to delete the button. That way, the menu would be deleting the button, not the button itself.

You would need to add the `TPopupMenu` onto the form having one single element - deleting the button.

```
  object mnu1: TPopupMenu
    object mniFreeBM: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'Free the button'
      OnClick = mniFreeBMClick
    end
  end

  procedure TForm18.mniFreeBMClick(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    FreeAndNil( Self.btnMenu );
  end;
```

Then you would have to connect that menu to the button.

```
.....
Self.FTableButton := TButton.Create(self);                        
//   FTableButton.OnMouseUp := ButtonMouseUp;   -- no more doing it! bad style!
Self.PopupMenu := mnu1;
mnu1.AutoPopup := True;
.....
```

Here we go. When user would R-click the button - there would come the menu, asking him if he wants to delete that button. If he does - then menu, not the button itself, would be freeing it. If users cancels the menu - then it was his random action and he want the button to be kept alive.

That is the better approach as I see.

2) other approaches revolve around idea of time delay, they assure that button only *asks* Delphi to be deleted someday *later*, but there would be *no immediate* kill.

Delphi when realizing it was asked to do it, would then delete the button some later time, after `OnMouseUp` procedure (and probably few other event-handling procedures too) are long executed and exited.
If the application is not heavy loaded with looong heaaavy computations, then that "later" is very very short actually. Most probably the user would never be able to see the difference. For playing safe, the button might also make itself invisible until someone would delete it.

There can be many approaches to do it, but I would list two.

2.1) DSM in his answer outlines `Post_Message`-centered approach. That is a good solid "old school" code. It is fast. It is well-understood. But it also has some limitations.

a) it only works on Windows. Forget Android, iOS and others. Well, if you only intend to work on Windows then you can just use standard VCL buttons which can suicide safely, at least in Delphi XE2.

b) it needs you to make a lot of boiler plate, like declaring extra procedures and constants.

c) it is unsafe - you have to make hard unchecked typecasts between integers and button pointers. Easy to make mistake typing/refactoring.

d) you need to understand Windows implementation: message loop, VCL place inside that message loop, difference between PostMessage, SendMessage and Perform, etc.

That is not a rocket science. For any "old school" desktop programmer it is easy and well known. Well, if you were one you would not ask such a question.

Another approach would use multi-threading. From performance perfectionism point of view that is abomination. Creating a new thread (quite the expensive operation!) just to call back and ask the button to be deleted - is very inefficient. But - that way you have much less code to write. You can use standard Delphi features that would most probably work with every operating system and every forms/buttons library, in current and future Delphi versions.

The code is like that.

```
procedure TForm18.btnThreadMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  ......
  if mbRight = Button then
     TThread.CreateAnonymousThread( procedure
       begin
         TThread.CurrentThread.Synchronize( nil, procedure
           begin
             FreeAndNil( btnThread );
           end
         );
       end
     ).Start;
end;
```

This way when you exit the `OnMouseButtonUp` the button is not being deleted, there only is incoming request from the temporary thread to delete it. When the form would work that request out may differ, but anyway it would be another event that happens after you safely exited the button's event handler. *Unless you used another abomination `ProcessMessages` but you did not and hopefully you never ever would.*

Comment: It's not that simple. You cannot destroy an object from its own event handler.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are probably right, at very least the button would have to "unpress" itself.... So we have to introduce something like `.Release` ? Perhaps wrap the call into `TThread.Synchronize` ?

Comment: The method might be a method of the form, but it was invoked by the button. Which means that when the event handler returns, it will be executing button code.

Comment: yep, on the second though I got it. But then, would main vcl thread Synchronize post messages or just shortcut itself to direct execution? because traditional way to do it with PostMessage is not merely platform dependent, but would introduce too many new issues for the novice user. Well, the easiest way would be introducing Popup Menu I guess....

Comment: There's not a simple, built-in way to solve this in a platform independent way

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - there is `TThread.CreateAnonymousThread` but it looks like a bit of abomination if too look from Win32-centered API level... Additionally I wonder if assumption that `TThread.Synchronize` is executed from outside of controls event handlers a safe platform independent one or merely a fleeting VCL implementation details.

Comment: Stop shouting and we can talk

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `You cannot destroy an object from its own event handler` - that is speculation, not the fact. It might be true sometimes. But "might" is not "is". `Which means that when the event handler returns, it will be executing button code` which does not necessarily mean there would happen something erratic or dangerous. VCL TButton is perfectly okay with being deleted form its own mouse event.

Comment: In all versions of the VCL? You might get away with it for this particular event in this particular version of the compiler. But the practise is wrong, well known to be wrong. If you want to do that, go ahead. But with my comments and voting, I will present a counter viewpoint.

Comment: Is it *documented* that such behavior is prohibited for Delphi GUI controls, or is it just your common sense ? Because one way to say "that is bad practice that may lead to errors" and another is blanket "you can not". First is correct, second is not.